# Sleep function error 453

Tags: excel, vba

I have run the following program on vba excel 2010 32 bit computer :

> Declare Sub sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwmilliseconds As Long)
>
> Sub game()
>
> i = 0
>
> Do
>
> ```
> i = i + 1
>
> Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 0)
> sleep 500
> ```
>
> Loop Until i > 10
>
> End Sub

But, after running, it shows me the following error :

"Can't find dll entry point sleep in kernel32"

Can somebody please tell me what I should do next to remove the error?

Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Try capital "S" in Sleep

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sleep 500 you might want to use:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Transistor is correct. You have to use capital "S". All API declarations are case sensitive.

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

An alternative to `Sleep` is to use the function `Wait` which I created few years ago and I still use it.

```
Sub Sample()
    i = 0
    Do
        i = i + 1
        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 0)
        Wait 1
    Loop Until i > 10
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```